# Нужна ли ссылка в идиоме обнаружения?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Если я проверяю, есть ли у типа функция `.begin()`, то нужно это делать с сылкой или без? И объясните почему?

```
using namespace std;

template<class, class = void>
struct supports_begin : false_type {};

template<class ContainerType>
struct supports_begin<ContainerType, 
                      void_t<decltype(declval<ContainerType/*&*/>().begin())>> : true_type {};
```

> У меня нет возможности использовать c++20.

Comment: А зачем там вообще может быть нужна ссылка?

Comment: Видел такое в хромиум - https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/template_util.h;l=70

Comment: Ну, поскольку [`declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) *Converts any type T to a reference type*, то вроде как от ссылки хуже не будет, но смысла нет... *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Но в этом примере `declvar` не от параметра шаблона.

Answer (score 1):

Если в `declval` указать не ссылку, то он сам добавит к типу `&&`.

То есть `declval<T>()` и `declval<T &&>()` - одно и то же, а `declval<T &>()` - отличается.

Можно написать такой метод, который можно будет вызвать только на lvalue, или только на rvalue - тогда разница будет заметна. Но сомневаюсь, что кто-то будет делать это с `.begin()`.

Видимо автор кода решил (вполне логично), что `.begin()` обычно вызывают на lvalue, поэтому правильнее проверять его наличие именно на lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от того, какой интерфейс вы хотите предоставить. Например, можно вызвать `supports_begin<std::string>&&`, `supports_begin<std::string>&` и `supports_begin<const std::string>`. Должна ли метафункция возвращать разные результаты?

Очевидный способ применения интерфейса:

```cpp
template<class Rng, std::enable_if_t<has_begin_method<Rng&&>::value, bool> = true>
auto customBegin(Rng&& rhg){
   return std::forward<Rng>(rng).begin();
}
template<class Rng, std::enable_if_t<(!has_begin_method<Rng&&>::value)&&(has_std_begin<Rgn&&>::value), bool> = true>
auto customBegin(Rng&& rhg){
   return std::begin(std::forward<Rng>(rng));
}
```

В этом случае аргументом может быть rvalue, mutable lvalue, или const lvalue , в во всех случаях может быть вызван разный метод begin. При использовании `std::declval<const T&>()` подойдут только контейнеры, у которых есть метод `begin() const`. Вероятно, это не то, что нужно. При использовании `std::declval<T&>()` подойдут любые контейнеры, реализующие  `begin() const` или `begin()&`, т.е. все стандартные контейнеры.

Но технически никто не запрещает контейнеру предоставить метод `begin()&&`, но не предоставить `begin()&`. Смысла в этом не много, но если пользователь реализует такой контейнер, для него будет неожиданно при вызове `customBegin(std::move(myContainer))` получить сообщения об ошибках.  При использовании `std::declval<T>()` или `std::declval<T&&>()` такой проблемы нет, поведение будет наиболее ожидаемым.  Если бы речь шла не о `begin()`, поддержка всех типов ссылок явно была бы ожидаемой. Например, при использовании паттерна builder, завершающий метод build можно вызвать только один раз, логично разрешать его только для rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку `declval`

> Converts any type T to a reference type

то хуже от ссылки быть не должно, но смысла в ее использовании нет...

P.S. В вашем примере по ссылке

```
// Uses expression SFINAE to detect whether using operator<< would work.
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct SupportsOstreamOperator : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct SupportsOstreamOperator<T,
                               decltype(void(std::declval<std::ostream&>()
                                             << std::declval<T>()))>
    : std::true_type {};
```

в `declval` передается `std::ostream&`, но это несколько иное — поскольку `std::ostream&` не является параметром шаблона, хотя, на мой взгляд, это не принципиальное отличие, так как работать будет и без `&` — https://ideone.com/lXeENJ.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*